# 'Use of unresolved identifier'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, identifier

In the code:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask){
    firstBody = contact.bodyA
    secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & photoTorpedoCategory) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & alienCategory) != 0){
        torpedoDidCollideWithAlien(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, alien: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)
    }
}

func torpedoDidCollideWithAlien(torpedo:SKSpriteNode, alien:SKSpriteNode){
    print("HIT")
    torpedo.removeFromParent()
    alien.removeFromParent()
    aliensDestroyed++

    if (aliensDestroyed > 30){
        var transition:SKTransition = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
        var gameOverScene:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: true)
        self.view!.presentScene(gameOverScene, transition: transition)
    }
}
```

It gives me an error on:

aliensDestroyed++     //<- Use of unresolved identifier 'aliensDestroyed'

if (aliensDestroyed > 30){        //<- Use of unresolved identifier 'aliensDestroyed'

var gameOverScene:SKScene = GameOverScene(size: self.size, won: true)  //<- Use of unresolved identifier 'GameOverScene'

I hope any of you can help.
(Sorry for my rookie questions)

Comment: "Use of unresolved identifier" means that the compiler doesn't recognize the name. Make sure that you have spelled "aliensDestroyed" correctly and it's accessible where you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variable aliansDestroyed and GameOverScene before you call on them. For example, aliansDestroyed becoming greater than thirty because Xcode has no idea what aliansDestroyed is.